# Не получаеться перевести python обьект в json

Tags: python, json, ооп, объекты

Не получается перевести python объект в json. У меня есть модель User:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    name = Column(String)
    time_created = Column(Integer)
    gender = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    last_name = Column(String)
    ip = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    premium = Column(Boolean)
    birth_day = Column(String)
    balance = Column(Float)
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    my_bet = relationship("Bet", back_populates="owner")
```

по которой создается объект юзер:

```
db_user = models.User(name=user.name, time_created=user.time_created, gender=user.gender, age=user.age,
                      last_name=user.last_name, ip=user.ip, city=user.city, premium=user.premium,
                      birth_day=user.birth_day, balance=user.balance, user_id=user.user_id)
```

при выводе самого объекта юзера он выводиться как:

```
<models.User object at 0x110473d00>
```

но при переводе его в json формат выводиться null:

```
call = json.dumps(db_user.__init__(name=user.name, time_created=user.time_created, gender=user.gender, age=user.age,
                      last_name=user.last_name, ip=user.ip, city=user.city, premium=user.premium,
                      birth_day=user.birth_day, balance=user.balance, user_id=user.user_id))
```

Как возможно это исправить и в чем ошибка. Пробовал передавать и сам объект, и encode и создавать класс новый юзера и туда передать еще и потом переводить в json, нечего не помогает. Возможно кто-то встречал такое прежде, в чем может быть ошибка и какое решение данной проблемы?

Comment: А какой итоговый результат вы ожидаете? Вы же понимаете, что json может состоять только из списков/словарей, которые содержат строки и числа? Как в вашем понимании должен выглядеть объект после перевода в джсон?

Comment: на сколько я понял, вы используете SQLAlchemy, в этом случае вам может быть полезен [данный](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json) топик